# How to use dynamic height for tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am using `UITableView` to display my data from realm. I am having two types of row one with `UIImageView` and other without `UIImageView`. If there is Image in `UIImageView` the height of row should be 207 or `UIImageView` is nil the height of row should be 64.

My coding:

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return msgs.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! collCell
    let msg = msgs[indexPath.row]
    var decodeImgURL = ""
    cell.lbl1.text = msg.content

    decodeImgURL = msg.imgurl

    if decodeImgURL == "none" {
        cell.img.isHidden = true
    } else {

        let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded:decodeImgURL,options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        let decodedImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
        cell.img.image = decodedImage

    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! collCell
    if cell.img.image != nil {
        return 207
    } else {
        return 64
    }

}
```

I am getting an error at `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! collCell`

Comment: @Moritz ok i understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same data in `heightForRowAt` as you use in `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let msg = msgs[indexPath.row]

    if msg.imgurl == "none" {
        print("row \(indexPath.row) does NOT have an image")
        return 64
    } else {
        print("row \(indexPath.row) DOES have an image")
        return 207
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could use auto-layout and constraints to auto-size the height of the rows... but that's another topic.

Comment: I updated my answer... see if you get valid print statements for the rows that have and do not have images.